# Can I say "What should be doing these days?" or is that wrong?

Tags: grammaticality, modal-verbs, questions, perfect-continuous

Is this right:

> What should I be doing these days?

The answer can be:

> You should be preparing for your exams these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I be doing these days? - Is correct.

Since it's an exam time, you must be paving the way for it. It's obviously taken that during this time, you (or anyone) should be studying hard.

The answer could be...

> Obviously, the exams are near. I should be studying all day!

Comment: I want to ask one translation. As you are Indian, I am writing in Hindi so that you can translate it. "Mai abhi baat ni kar skta kyoki mere yaha light nahi aa rahi." Can you translate it for me?

Comment: @hellodear2 *Light nahi aa rahi* means there's no power (I'm guessing). It should be then - *I cannot talk to you now since there's no power.*

Comment: @hellodear2 see this - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12530/hindi-speakers-room I made a special room for people like you.

Comment: And how will you say this: "andar aajao, Light aa gayi hai".

Comment: come to chat. Such discussion cannot be comments here. We should keep this site clean.